# degenerating surface

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, dg.differential-geometry, blow-ups, branched-covers

Hi,
i have a sequence of immersed disc $u_n: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ which converge to a singular cover of the disc: $z^k$ for $k\geq 2$, moreprecisely  $u_n \rightarrow z^k$ in $C^2(\mathbb{D})$. Of course the Gauss curvature of the image $\Sigma_n=u_n(\mathbb{B})$ blows up thanks to Gauss-Bonnet formula : $\int_{\Sigma_n}K= (1-k)2\pi + o(1)$. My questions are the following:

1) can the Gauss curvature be bounded form above? i.e the blow-up come only from necks and there is no pinching region... my feeeling is no, since you have to close the surface.

2) Extra bonus: same question with only a convergence in $C^2_{loc}(\mathbb{D}\setminus \{ 0\})$, here we allow the closing of the surface be made by a big sphere for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When $k$ is odd, there does exist such a family of immersions satisfying Paul's requirements.  (When $k$ is even, Vitali Kapovich has shown, using a clever topological argument, that it's not possible to have such a family of degenerating immersions.  Please see his answer for the details.)

Set $k=2m+1$, and consider the (complex) $1$-parameter family of maps $u_t:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ given by
$$
u_t(z) = \bigl(Re(z^{2m+1}-(2m{+}1)t^2z),\ Im(z^{2m+1}+(2m{+}1)t^2z),\ 
          \tfrac{4m+2}{m+1} Re(t z^{m+1})\ \bigr).
$$
These smooth maps converge smoothly to $u_0$ as $t\to0$,
and $u_t$ induces the metric 
$$
ds_t^2 = (2m{+}1)^2\bigl(|z|^{2m}+|t|^2\bigr)^2 |dz|^2.
$$
Thus, $u_t$ is an immersion for $t\not=0$,
while $u_0(z) = \bigl(Re(z^{2m+1}),\ Im(z^{2m+1}),\ 0\ \bigr)$.

The family $u_t$ was constructed using the Weierstrass formula for minimal immersions, so the image $u_t({\mathbb{C}})\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is an immersed minimal surface, and, as a result, the Gauss curvature is everywhere non-positive.  In fact, for $t\not=0$, the Gauss curvature only vanishes at $z=0$, and then only when $m>1$.  In particular, all of these degenerating immersions have curvature bounded above.

Answer (score 12):

for question 1) it's not clear to me why $C^2$ approximating $z \mapsto z^k$ by immersions is possible at all. do you have an example of such a sequence?

edit: Ok, I thought some more on the topological issue of whether it's always possible to deform $z \mapsto z^k$ to an immersion in $C^2$ and I can say that it is definitely **NOT possible**  if $k$ is even. In particular, it's impossible when $k=2$. There is an easy necessary condition for an existence of such deformation. An immersion $f$ of a disk gives a parallelization of the tangent bundle along $f$, i.e we get a map $f'\colon D^2\to V_2(\mathbb R^3)$ where $V_2(\mathbb R^3)$ is the Stiefel manifold of  orthonormal  2-frames in $\mathbb R^3$ which is of course just $SO(3)$. This map ought to extend the map on the boundary of the disk $S^1$ which being an immersion already won't change much under a small deformation. That map is essentially given by $z\to kz^{k-1}$ which disregarding the conformal factor $k$ can be thought of as a map $S^1\to SO(2)=V_2^{or}(\mathbb R^2)\subset V_2(\mathbb R^2)=O(2)$. The natural map $V_2(\mathbb R^2)\to V_2(\mathbb R^3)$  corresponds to the standard inclusion $SO(2)\to SO(3)$ on identity component. Now, $\pi_1(SO(2))\cong \mathbb Z$ and $\pi_1(SO(3))\cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and the map $\pi_1(SO(2))\to \pi_1(SO(3))$ is well-known to be onto (as is immediate from the long exact sequence for the fibration $SO(2)\to SO(3)\to S^2$).

That means that the map $z\mapsto z^{k-1}$ gives a generator of $\pi_1(SO(3))$ when $k$ is even  and thus can not be extended to $D^2$.

(Note that this takes care of **both** 1) and 2) when $k$ is even.)

I think the above necessary condition should also be sufficient  and therefore when $k$ is odd  such a deformation should always be possible (at least in $C^0$) as evidenced by $k=1$ of course. I'm not at all an expert on immersions but the subject is very well understood and I hope someone who knows more about it will chime in.

OK, Robert Bryant answered this (see below). Moreover, a direct calculation shows that his example produces a family of immersions $f_t$ with with the induced metrics $ds_t^2$ having $sec\le 0$ for all $t>0$. This settles the original question in the positive for $k$ odd.

<strike>For question 2) you can not expect any upper curvature bounds. Given an  immersion you can locally  perturb it on an arbitrary small neighborhood of 0 by adding a small thin "finger" to your surface. this will introduce some arbitrary positive (and negative) curvature. Doing this along a given sequence converging in $C^2_{loc}(\mathbb D\backslash \{0\})\cap C^0(\mathbb D)$ will keep such convergence.</strike>

Comment: got you. then please disregard my original answer about 2). Note however that my edit above  shows that when $k$ is even you can not **at all** extend the immersion $z\to z^k$ near the boundary $S^1$ to an immersion $D^2\to \mathbb R^3$. this does take care of both 1) and 2) in that case. I don't really want to think about possible  geometric restrictions when $k$ is odd until I'm certain it's actually possible.

Comment: The case $k=2m+1$ does occur.  Consider the (complex) $1$-parameter family of maps $u_t:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ given by
$$
u_t(z) = \bigl(Re(z^{2m+1}-(2m{+}1)t^2z),\ Im(z^{2m+1}+(2m{+}1)t^2z),\ 
          \tfrac{4m+2}{m+1} Re(t z^{m+1})\ \bigr).
$$
These smooth maps converge smoothly to $u_0$ as $t\to0$
and $u_t$ induces the metric 
$$
ds_t^2 = (2m{+}1)^2\bigl(|z|^{2m}+|t|^2\bigr)^2 |dz|^2.
$$
Thus, $u_t$ is an immersion for $t\not=0$,
while $u_0(z) = \bigl(Re(z^{2m+1}),\ Im(z^{2m+1}),\ 0\ \bigr)$.

Comment: Thank you Vitali and Robert for your proof of the fact an immersion is possible if and only if $k$ is odd.

Comment: @Robert Bryant This is a really nice example!! It was pretty clear to me that a $C^0$ approximation like this near 0 is possible but I wasn't sure if it can still happen with $C^2$ convergence. Note that your example also answers the original question by the OP because $ds_t^2$ has nonpositive sectional curvature for all $t>0$.

Comment: @Vitali:  Thanks.  Actually, I didn't realize that this is what Paul was asking in 1).  I thought that he was asking whether you could *prove* an upper bound for the curvature, not whether there was *some* example with an upper bound.  Now that I read over the question again, I realize that your interpretation makes more sense than mine.  I did know that the curvature was nonpositive everywhere, since, after all, these immersions are minimal surfaces.  I guess I should claim the reward, or should we split it.

Comment: @Robert Paul edited the question as it originally did seem to ask if the curvature is always bounded above - I got caught on that too (see my original answer to 2) above). But he made clear what he wants in the comments. You should claim the bounty as you did answer the main question and I don't think it can be split anyway.